# Bitcoin Hash/TXID or Receipts

Tags: transactions, multi-signature

Does obtaining Bitcoin receipts from Blockchair.com or Blockexplorer.one makes you an owner of a wallet or the address?

Answer (score 1):

No, owning bitcoins requires being able to spend it. This necessitates being in possession of the private key corresponding to the address.